# Does authlogic support JWT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, authlogic

I've read the documentation, but I'm a bit confused. It doesn't mention JWT. I could try following this [JWT Tutorial](https://dev.to/mohhossain/a-complete-guide-to-rails-authentication-using-jwt-403p), but it feels like I'd be reimplementing parts of authlogic and generally fighting the gem.

Does anyone have any tips on the best way to proceed?